# read through each line and check if line start with a specific string using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying read all lines in `out.txt` and check if that starts with word `No`. If the line starts with `No`, I am echoing `yes` to file `1.txt`, else `no` to `2.txt`
I am using below code :

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (out.txt) do (

IF "%%A:~0,2%"=="No" (

@echo yes >> 1.txt

)else (

@echo no >> 2.txt

)
)
```

but its nit working for me. seems like the if statement is not working correctly. Can someone please tell me if there is something wrong with the code ?. I tried to echo `%%A` and is reading the lines as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot substring a *metavariable*.

Try

```
findstr /b /L "No"  out.txt >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo not found
) else (
 echo found
)
```

which  finds any line in the file that `/b` begins `/L` with the literal `No` and outputs any found. The `>nul` disposes of the output. `errorlevel` is set to `0` if the string was found, non-zero otherwise.

Comment: Interesting and simple, but it requires the invocation of findstr.exe.

Answer (score 1):

This is faster:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set prompt=$G

@for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (out.txt) do @call :DoIt "%%A"
@exit /b 0

:DoIt
@set _line=%~1
@set _linePrefeix=%_line:~0,2%
@if "%_linePrefeix%" equ "No" (@echo yes >> 1.txt) else (@echo no >> 2.txt)
@exit /b 0
```

Magoo's solution and this one both require two processes, but this one involves an executable image that is already loaded into memory (cmd.exe).

Comment: Can't say that I have seen CALL work faster then just doing all the work inside the FOR command.  You could get rid of one SET command in your code and just use the substring with the IF comparison.